# Using lambda in defining value in dict

Tags: python

I'd like to use `lambda` in defining value in dict.

I still get `syntax error`, I don't even know if this way works

Example:

```
x = []

x.append({
    "a": "lol",
    "b": (lambda b: b if b is "rofl")("rofl")
})

x.append({
    "a": "lol",
    "b": (lambda b: b if b is not None)("123")
})

# Expected output:
# x: [{"a": "lol", "b": "rofl"}, {"a": "lol", "b": None}]
```

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't ask a question. This code will cause a SyntaxError though because your `if` conditional expression isn't complete in each case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an "else" statement :

```
x = []

x.append({
    "a": "lol",
    "b": (lambda b: b if b is "rofl" else "foo")("rofl")
})

x.append({
    "a": "lol",
    "b": (lambda b: b if b is not None else "bar")("123")
})
print(x)
# [{'a': 'lol', 'b': 'rofl'}, {'a': 'lol', 'b': '123'}]
```